# GnuCash Chargeback

Tags: gnucash, chargeback

I am trying to use the chargeback function in Gnucash. The chargeback
customer and job are both specified when I create the bill and the
"Billable" column is checked on all items on the bill. However, I cannot see
any option to link this Bill to an Invoice that I send to a customer.

Could you please help me how the chargeback option works in GnuCash?

Thank you,
Marcell

Answer (score 2):

There is no dedicated function. There is no “button” you have to click.

Just create a new invoice for the customer in question (Business → Customer → New Invoice) and GnuCash will automatically fill this invoice with all billable items you have collected items for (for which you already have posted [vendor] bills).

You then need to tick the “Invoiced?” column for all items you would like to charge the customer now (i. e. these items will be listed in the invoice you send out). So, you may withhold items, e. g. because they haven’t been delivered yet.

<sub>PS: Your question is warranted though. The GnuCash documentation should explain that behavior. I just struggled with that issue on my own. I’m a *novice* user. Unfortunately GnuCash is a lot trial and error.</sub>